# How to fetch the latest record from ArrayList based on date

Tags: java, java-8

I have list of records as below. I want to fetch the latest record based on date and set its name as 'H'. In the same way I want to set 'L' as name for all remaining records.

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();

try {
  studentList.add(new Student("A", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-1990")));
  studentList.add(new Student("B", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-2010")));
  studentList.add(new Student("C", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-2011")));
  studentList.add(new Student("D", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-2012")));
  studentList.add(new Student("E", new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("01-01-2018")));

} catch (ParseException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();  
}

Student student = Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate()));
```

I've tried as above but here I can set name only for latest record but I'm unable to set name for all other remaining records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not trim the size, and get the last index?

Comment: why not just sort the Collection and set `H` for one and `L` for the rest of them?

Comment: what if two students have the same date that is the max in sorting, which one would you set as `H` and which as `L`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only date please use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java-8

```
studentList.add(new Student("A", LocalDate.parse("01-01-1990", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")));
```

So the `Student` class will be

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private date LocalDate;

    //getters and setters

   }
```

Now use `Collections.max` Since `LocalDate` implements `Comparable`

```
Student student =  Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate()));
```

**To Set `H` and `L`**

**1st aaproach**

The approach i would suggest here is first set `name = L` for every student using `forEach`

```
studentList.forEcah(stu->stu.setName("L"));
```

Now just get the max student using comparator and set name = `H`

```
Student student =  Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate()));
student.setName("H");
```

**2nd approach**

You can sort the `List` first

```
studentList.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate()).reversed());
```

And then Set name = `H` for first record and `L` for rest of them

```
IntStream.range(0,studentList.size())
         .forEach(i->{
              if(i==0) {
                 studentList.get(i).setName("H");
                }
                else {
               studentList.get(i).setName("L");
               }
             });
```

Comment: from the question - *i tried as above but here i can set name only for latest record where as i am unable to set name for all other remaining records?*

Comment: I didn’t understand your question, @Naman. The answer shows how to set the name to `L` on all other remaining records.

Answer (score 4):

Single-threaded version:

```
// Find the latest student in the list 
Student latest = Collections.max(studentList,
                                 Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate()));

// Iterate the list, setting each student's name depending on whether it
// is the latest or not. 
studentList.forEach(s -> {s.setName(s == latest ? "H" : "L");});
```

The above code makes two passes through the list.  There are other ways to do the second step; e.g.

```
studentList.forEach(s -> {s.setName("L");});
latest.setName("H");
```

The `max` call will throw `NoSuchElementException` if the collection is empty.  You could either treat that as an error (i.e. let the exception propagate), or test for an empty list before you start.

---

A one pass solution is possible using streams:

```
Optional<Student> latest = studentList.stream()
                .peek(s -> {s.setName("L")})
                .max(Comparator.comparing(s -> s.getDate());
latest.ifPresent(s -> {s.setName("H")});
```

We set every student's name to `"L"` and find the latest in one pass.
Then we reset the latest student's name to `"H"`.

This version also works for an empty list.  (Indeed, we would need to work hard to make it not work.  `Optional` is helpful in some contexts.)

If the list was long enough, might be worth using `parallel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your list and set the name as you need:

```
Student student = Collections.max(studentList, Comparator.comparing(Student::getDate));
studentList.forEach(s -> s.name = s.equals(student) ? "H" : "L");
```

Comment: Of course the printing is not neccessary. I was hoping that would be obvious, but you might be right that not everyone knows that. Edited, thanks...